# Password Protected Database still visible in Windows Authentication Mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have created a SQL Server database with SQL Server authentication mode to protect my database from password.

But when I open SQL Server in Windows authentication mode, my database is still showing. I want that my database should not be visible publicly.

Please help....

Comment: The modes affect *your* connection to the *server*. They have nothing to do with individual databases. What permissions you gain when connecting via either mode is a function of how the server is configured.

Comment: So is there any other way to protect my database from public mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to disable windows authentication login to your sql server.

Follow the below steps to disable windows authentication:-\

1) Login to your sql server using sql server authentication.

2) You'll see folders like Databases, security, Server Objects etc.

3) Expand the Security Folder. Expand the login folder. Here you will see the users of your sql server. You'll be able to see the user for which windows authentication is there. Make sure that the user selected is correct.

4) Right Click that user and select properties(the last option).

5) A new window will open and select status from the top left. Its under select page section.

6) chose deny under settings on the right.

7) chose disabled under the login section.

8) Click Ok.